# Multiple fetches with EAGER type in Hibernate with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have an entity which contains:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assessment")
@OrderBy(value = "order ASC")
private List<AssessmentPart> assessmentParts = new LinkedList<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assessment")
private List<AssessmentText> texts = new LinkedList<>();
```

as you see there are two collections which needs to be eagerly loaded. This is not working and hibernate throws an exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

That's because Hibernate can't fetch multiple collections with one go. But if I change the `List` to `Set` and the `LinkedList` to `HashSet` this part works fine but the other - more annoying issue occurs.

When I am trying to get the entity from the database using:

```
entityManager.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
```

It fails with:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier
```

I am sure that ID I am passing to `find` method is not null, I've debugged and I am sure of this. It somehow disappears inside Hibernate.

If I change collection types to `LAZY` everything just works without errors but there are some circumstances where I need to use `EAGER`.

Does anybody have a solution how to fix it? Either I could have a set but prevent assertion error from occurring or I could have a list but somehow avoid multiple fetch bags error.

I am using:

```
Hibernate 4.2.2.Final
Tomcat 7
JPA 2.0
JDK 1.7
```

**EDIT**

I've just discovered that adding `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` fixes the issue and I can use multiple list with `EAGER` type, but is there anyway to solve this by not using Hibernate specific annotations? And why it fixed the issue in the first place?

Comment: There is an answer saying exactly that... you should accept his answer... just saying.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that when Hibernate fetches SQL query results there is no simple way to tell which child element belongs to which collection. See [this blog entry](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html) for more detailed explanation with an example. To summarize you have following workarounds:

- Load each collection separately using subselect `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)`
- Force usage of list instead of bag by adding index column `@IndexColumn(name="LIST_INDEX")`
- Use unordered collection like Set.

Comment: As Hibernate documentation say (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/IndexColumn.html), @ IndexColumn is deprecated. I'd recomment using JPA's @ OrderColumn (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html).

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Hibernate and you do not care using Hibernate annotations :

Annotate your collection fields with:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

Remember to remove the fetchType attribute from the @OneToMany annotation.

Comment: This is a hibernate specific annotation