# Hibernate : org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Tags: java, hibernate

**Entity classes**

**Customer**

```
       @Entity
        @Table(name="Custumer")
        public class Custumer implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name="id")
            private Long id;
            @Column(name="name",unique = true)
            private String name;
            @Column(name="Email",unique = true)
            private String Email;
            @Column(name = "Coins")
            private Double coins;

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

            private List<ShippingAdress> shippingAdress = new ArrayList<ShippingAdress>();


            @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "custumer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)

            private List<Order> orders= new LinkedList<Order>();
//...
```

**ShippingAdress**

```
    @Entity
        @Table(name="ShippingAdress")
        public class ShippingAdress implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name="id")
            private Long id;
            @Column(name="postCode")
            private String PostCode;
            @Column(name="street")
            private String street;
            @Column(name="house")
            private String house;
            @Column(name="flat")
            private String flat;

            @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shippingAdress")
            private List<Custumer> custumers = new LinkedList<Custumer>();
    //...
```

**Items**

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="Items")
    public class Items implements  Serializable,Comparable<Items>  {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;
        @Column(name="name", unique = true)
        private String name;
        @Column(name="price")
        private double price;
        @Column(name="count")
        private int count;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
        List<Order> orders = new LinkedList<Order>();
    //...
```

**CustomerOrder**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CustumerOrder")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Custumer custumer;


    @Id
    @ManyToOne

    private Items item;
```

When I'm trying to get all orders from particular customer

```
  public List<Order> getOrderByCustumerId(Custumer custumer) {

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class);
        List<Order> res = (List<Order>) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("custumer",custumer)).list();

        return res;
    }
```

I'm facing the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

If delete `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` from one of the places they are existed 
getting the following:
(supposed  deleted from customer )

```
   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.CoinsShop.DataBase.DataSets.Custumer.shippingAdress, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

relations in DB

[image: database relations]

Comment: Please have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566304/multiple-fetches-with-eager-type-in-hibernate-with-jpa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the exception says to you, you can't fetch two related collections or bags simultaneously. A quick solution would be to remove the `FetchType.EAGER` from one collection and force the fetching of that collection explicitly calling the collection objects.

For example, if you remove the `FetchType.EAGER` from `shippingAddress` collection, you can force the fetching like this:

```
public List<Order> getOrderByCustomerId(Customer customer) {
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class);
    List<Order> res = (List<Order>) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("customer",customer)).list();

    for (Order order : res)
        order.getCustomer().getShippingAddress().size();

    return res;
}
```

Calling the `size()` method of the collection will force the fetching of all the elements of that collection.

More information about this topic:

[Hibernate cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334970/hibernate-cannot-simultaneously-fetch-multiple-bags)