# Spring boot JPA many to many asoociation with extra columns causing Multiple Bag exceptions

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hello i am new to spring boot if you could help me out it would be really appreciated!!!

Consider i have following tables

buses
routes
bus_routes
driver
driver_routes
busstop
busstop_routes

buses and routes has a connection table bus_routes with additional columns
bus_routes structure
id bus_id route_id created updated is_active

As my knowlege using @ManytoMany is not possible because it has additional columns other than bus_id and route_id

from the solutions i found up online i used joins following way

Bus.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bus", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BusRoutes> busRoutes;
```

BusRoutes.java

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Bus bus;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Route route;
```

Routes.java
//As routes has connection with other three table

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "route", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BusRoutes> busRoutes;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "route", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<DriverRoutes> driverRoutes;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "route", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<RouteBusStops> routeStops;
```

so when i try to execute multiple bag exception,any ideas how to solve this??
also can i fetch just contents of route yables without any bags??,is it possible??
What is the most efficient method for many to many with extra columns???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate : org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282850/hibernate-org-hibernate-loader-multiplebagfetchexception-cannot-simultaneousl)